# Prototype function doesn't run onclick & doesn't perform correctly anyway

Tags: javascript, html, css

There are 2 problems with this attempt:

1) I don't know how to get the button to call the JS prototype function onclick as the prototype function is not named like a normal function

2) The prototype function should apparently run anyway and change the paragraph tag with the text described in the JS function, but it does not run

Could someone advise what I'm doing wrong here? Particularly with number 2 as I cannot see any errors in the coding.

Really appreciate the help, thank you.

```js
function house(bedrooms, bathrooms, floors) {
  this.bedrooms = bedrooms;
  this.bathrooms = bathrooms;
  this.floors = floors;
  // objects
}

house.prototype.methodexample = function() {
  document.getElementById("prototype-example").innerHTML = "The prototype property can also be used with functions.";
}
```

```css
@charset "UTF-8";

/* CSS Document */

body {
  height: 1000px;
  width: 100%;
  background: #fff;
  margin: 0;
}

#javascript-essentials {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  background: #eff2f7;
}

#javascript-programming-techniques {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  background: #F0F9FC;
}

.divider {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  background: #CCC;
  display: block;
  margin: 10px;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 25px;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  margin: 10px;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

h2 {
  font-size: 20px;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  margin: 10px;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

h3 {
  font-size: 16px;
  display: block;
}

#prototype-example {}
```

```html
<!-- Checklist: Prototype -->
<article class="divider">
  <h3>Prototype Property</h3>
  <p>The prototype property adds new properties or methods to Javascript objects.</p>
  <p>NOT WORKING!!!!!!!!!!!!!</p>
  <p id="prototype-example"></p>
  <button onclick="______________">Click Me</button>
</article>
```

Comment: You can call it directly: `house.prototype.methodexample()`, and in your case that would work because your method doesn't do anything with instance properties (it doesn't refer to `this`), but it doesn't make sense to have a prototype method that doesn't refer to instance properties, so normally you would create an instance of `house` and call it via the instance. Regarding your point 2 that it should run anyway, why would it? It won't run unless you call it. (As an aside, I don't think any of that CSS is at all relevant to what you're asking - there is no need to include it in the question.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a `house` object, then call the method on that object.

```js
function house(bedrooms, bathrooms, floors) {
  this.bedrooms = bedrooms;
  this.bathrooms = bathrooms;
  this.floors = floors;
  // objects
}

house.prototype.methodexample = function() {
  document.getElementById("prototype-example").innerHTML = "The house has " + this.floors + " floors";
}

var myHouse = new house(2, 2, 3);
```

```css
@charset "UTF-8";

/* CSS Document */

body {
  height: 1000px;
  width: 100%;
  background: #fff;
  margin: 0;
}

#javascript-essentials {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  background: #eff2f7;
}

#javascript-programming-techniques {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  background: #F0F9FC;
}

.divider {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  background: #CCC;
  display: block;
  margin: 10px;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 25px;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  margin: 10px;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

h2 {
  font-size: 20px;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  margin: 10px;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

h3 {
  font-size: 16px;
  display: block;
}

#prototype-example {}
```

```html
<!-- Checklist: Prototype -->
<article class="divider">
  <h3>Prototype Property</h3>
  <p>The prototype property adds new properties or methods to Javascript objects.</p>
  <p>NOT WORKING!!!!!!!!!!!!!</p>
  <p id="prototype-example"></p>
  <button onclick="myHouse.methodexample()">Click Me</button>
</article>
```

Answer (score 1):

you have to instantiate house with keyword `new` , and any failed lookups for a method will delegate to the prototype automatically

```
   function house(bedrooms, bathrooms, floors) {
      this.bedrooms = bedrooms;
      this.bathrooms = bathrooms;
      this.floors = floors;
      // objects
    }

    house.prototype.methodexample = function() {
      document.getElementById("prototype-example").innerHTML = "The prototype property can also be used with functions.";
    }

    document.getElementById('button').addEventListener('click' , (new house).methodexample)
```

here is how you call if from html

```
  <button id='button' onClick="(new house).methodexample">Click Me</button>
```

Comment: That would work for the example function, but wouldn't work if the prototype method used `this` (which prototype methods usually would do).

Comment: could you give an example please !

Comment: I mean, say the prototype function said `...innerHTML = this.bedrooms`. If you bind the event listener as shown with `.addEventListener()` when the function is called `this` will be the clicked DOM element, not the instance of `house`. (Regarding your edit, in the `onclick` attribute you'd need `()` at the end.)

Answer (score 1):

Just like aeid said, you can either pass in a handler function to the button or even better attach an eventListener to it.

I'd recommend you to avoid using constructor functions and 'new'. Things get much cleaner and easier with an object literal or factory function, for example:

```
function house (bedrooms, bathrooms, floors) {
  return {
    bedrooms: bedrooms,
    bathrooms: bathrooms,
    floors: floors,
    methodExample: function () {
      document.getElementById("prototype-example").innerHTML = "The house has " + floors + " floors";
    }
  }
}

var MyHouse = house(3, 3, 2)

document.getElementById('button').addEventListener('click' , MyHouse.methodexample)
```

You get the advantage of a closure, which is far better then a constructor function.

alternatively you can create an object first with the factory and attach the method with `.prototype`

ps: with es6 it'd look even better